# Display string having words with multiple formatting

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

In my app, I am displaying user comment that is fetched from the server. The comment contains user name, tag and some text in bold.

**For example:**
    "`Nancy` tagged `Clothing:` **Season 2, Episode 5.** where do they find all the old clothes"

The words "Nancy" and "Clothing:" should be gray and orange color, respectively and "Season 2, Episode 5." should be bold.

I have tried using `NSAttributedString` but failed to achieve the above.

Following is the code I tried to change color but nothing changed. I am not very sure of how to use NSAttributedString.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *title = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:", tag.title]];
    [title addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:246/255.0 green:139/255.0 blue:5/255.0 alpha:1.0f] range:NSMakeRange(0,[title length])];
    self.tagCommentLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ tagged %@: %@ %@",tag.user.name , title, episode, tag.comment];
```

Can someone help me with a code as to how can I achieve the example sentence with the desired formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSAttributedString and NSString are two different things. If you want to add attributes to NSString (e.g. change the color of the text), you have to first make the NSString:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ tagged %@: %@ %@",tag.user.name , title, episode, tag.comment];
```

Then you make NSMutableAttributedString from your NSString and add attributes to it:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string]; 
[attString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:246/255.0 green:139/255.0 blue:5/255.0 alpha:1.0f] range:[string rangeOfString:title];
```

And when you want to display your attributed string, you should use .attributedText instead of .text:

```
self.tagCommentLabel.attributedText = attString;
```

Comment: But I don't want the whole string to have the same format. I want user name to be gray color, title to be orange color and episode be bold. The user name , title , episode and comment are different objects coming from the server. I am display these objects together into a sentence in the label `self.tagCommentLabel.text` as I showed in the example.

Comment: I understand they are different objects. In my example I just showed you, what you have to do in the code you posted in order to color the title. You can do the same for all of the different objects (strings) you get from the server. For example if you want to color the comment, you do this: [attString addAttribute ... range:[string rangeOfString:tag.comment]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add logic because I'm pretty sure you don't want to **always** color/bold this specific words, but here you go with a quick example:

```
NSString *title = @"Nancy tagged Clothing: Season 2, Episode 5. where do they find all the old clothes";
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title];

// Color text for range of string
[attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                         value:[UIColor grayColor]
                         range:[title rangeOfString:@"Nancy"]];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                         value:[UIColor grayColor]
                         range:[title rangeOfString:@"Clothing"]];

// Bold (be careful, I have used system font with bold and 14.0 size, change the values as for yourself)
[attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                         value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0 weight:UIFontWeightBold]
                         range:[title rangeOfString:@"Season 2"]];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                         value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0 weight:UIFontWeightBold]
                         range:[title rangeOfString:@"Season 5"]];

self.tagCommentLabel.attributesText = attributedString;
```

**Edit:** To make it work with your code, delete the line:

```
self.tagCommentLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ tagged %@: %@ %@",tag.user.name , title, episode, tag.comment];
```

Instead of mine assigning to title with static text, change it to:

```
NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ tagged %@: %@ %@",tag.user.name , title, episode, tag.comment];
```

Comment: The text is not hard coded. Its coming from the server. And yes those portion of the text always require to be color/bold. I tried your code and it gives me the same result as it gave me earlier. It prints this tagged `Mistakes{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0.5 0 1";
}` within the text